# document.getElementById().style.display = "block" doesnt work in same function as document.getElementById().innerText

Tags: javascript, html, forms, getelementbyid, onsubmit

I have a simple form that calls a function 'activate_loading' onsubmit. 'activate_loading' contains two lines of code to display a loading spinner and change text of submit button to 'Please wait':

```
        document.getElementById("loader_mini").style.display = "block";
```

changes the display of the loading spinner from display:none to display: block.

```
        document.getElementById("submitBtn").innerText = "Please Wait...";
```

changes the innerText of the button to 'Please Wait' instead of 'Submit'

Each line will works fine on it's own but when put together, the display of the loading spinner does not change from display:none to display: block. It seems that line

```
        document.getElementById("submitBtn").innerText = "Please Wait...";
```

causes

```
        document.getElementById("loader_mini").style.display = "block";
```

not to work.

1. I've tried switching the lines around which results in the same
   result.
2. I tried .style.visibility= "visible"; instead of display: block->
   same result.
3. I also noticed that  is taken out of the
   button element. The code works fine.
4. I tried switching browsers but it's the same result again (tried on chrome & firefox)

Does anyone have any ideas what the issue is? I'd really appreciate any help on this at all. The code seems pretty straight forward but i cant seem to see what's causing the issue.

```js
    function activate_loading() {

            document.getElementById("loader_mini").style.display = "block"; 
            document.getElementById("submitBtn").innerText = "Please Wait...";
       }
```

```css
#loader_mini{
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 2px solid blue;
        border-top: 2px solid white;
        border-left: 1px solid white;
        border-bottom: 0px solid white;
        border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-animation: spin 1.2s linear infinite;
        animation: spin 1.2s linear infinite;
        display: none;
      }
        
      @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0% {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
        
      @keyframes spin {
        0% {
          transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" class="hide_<?=$sent_status_show?>"
         onsubmit="activate_loading()">
         <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
         <input type="email" name="email"/>
         <br>
         <label for="subject">Email Subject:</label>
         <textarea name="subject"></textarea>
         <br>
         <button id="submitBtn" class="submitBtn" type="submit">
            Submit
            <div id="loader_mini">
            </div>
         </button>
     </form>
```

Comment: use the return statement onsubmit="return activate_loading()" and then pass true or false after doing the same thing.

Comment: `<div id="loader_mini">` is _inside_ your button. When you edit the button's `innerText`, it replaces everything inside with `"Please Wait..."`, including `<div id="loader_mini">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problem with your code:

1. You don't stop form submit so you can't see any change because page change.
2. You need to add loader after change text else the Text will delete loader.

What i did?

Delete inline onchange and add a function directly (more "elegant" code), then i add `event.preventDefault();` for stop submit.
Next step is change position of element `innerHTML` (was `innerText` but change for add loader).

```js
form.onsubmit = function(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  activate_loading();
};
function activate_loading() {            
  document.getElementById("submitBtn").innerHTML = "Please Wait...<div id='loader_mini'></div>";
  document.getElementById("loader_mini").style.display = "block"; 
}
```

```css
#loader_mini{
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 2px solid blue;
        border-top: 2px solid white;
        border-left: 1px solid white;
        border-bottom: 0px solid white;
        border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-animation: spin 1.2s linear infinite;
        animation: spin 1.2s linear infinite;
        display: none;
      }
        
      @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0% {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
        
      @keyframes spin {
        0% {
          transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post" class="hide_<?=$sent_status_show?>">
         <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
         <input type="email" name="email"/>
         <br>
         <label for="subject">Email Subject:</label>
         <textarea name="subject"></textarea>
         <br>
         <button id="submitBtn" class="submitBtn" type="submit">
            Submit            
         </button>
     </form>
```

Comment: PS. if you need to submit when you do what you want just use `form.submit();` on first function

Comment: I didnt add the event.preventDefault(); because I wanted my form to submit. I wanted the spinner and 'Please Wait..' text present while the page is loading before it redirects (especially incase of poor internet connection)

Comment: or is it better to do it the way you provided with  event.preventDefault(); then later include form.submit(); in order for it to submit like i want?

Comment: No it's ok so :)

Answer (score 0):

`.innerText` replaces all the content inside the button including the loader element.

That's why the loader disappear when you use innerText. The solution is to have two elements inside the button. One for the text and one for the loader. So when you use `.innerText`, you can use it on the text element instead of the whole button.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Makes sense. I tried this by adding <span> in my button text and changed the intertext of the span.